# Swirl loading issue

Tags: r, swirl

Downloaded `swirl` package, downloaded all the files for it in a zip but when running a command to unzip it in R, it shows the following msg

```
install_course_zip("~/Downloads/swirl_courses-master.zip", multi=TRUE, which_course="R Programming")
```

> Error in unzip(path, list = TRUE) : zip file
>   'C:/Users/sony/Documents/Downloads/swirl_courses-master.zip' cannot be
>   opened

Comment: `~/Downloads/swirl_courses-master.zip` is a unix path, not sure if window will interpret it the same way. You *are* on windows, aren't you? If not, the zip command is receiving a wrong path. And, on Unix, `Documents` and `Downloads` are at the same level.

Comment: i m using windows only, how to proceed now?

Comment: It has been a while, but you can normally install R packages directly from R itself. Start R, and at the command prompt, type `install.packages("swirl")`. R should take care of everything. You should be able to start `swirl` with two lines: `library("swirl")` and
`swirl()`

Comment: @jcoppens problem is not about installing swirl, and even if i m doing this way i am still not able to load the courses in swirl

Comment: Are you assisting some course? (maybe Coursera or edX)? You need to follow the instructions of the course (and possibly that course generates a key or password personally for you, which you have to use to get in the first time)

Comment: i m doing it on coursera but there is no key or password. The error simply says its a path issue

Comment: Ok. The key was for Swirl to send the assistance records back to Coursera, and give you the credit for solving the swirl exercises. I'll reply ''Officially" 'cause there's too much code.

Answer (score 0):

First step (after installing R, and starting R, of course):

```
> install.packages('swirl')
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL ...Your selected CPAN mirror...
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 98565 bytes (96 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 96 KB

* installing *source* package 'swirl' ...
** package 'swirl' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (swirl)

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/RtmpUfIWep/downloaded_packages'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

Do note, that at the start, when asked to select a CPAN mirror, a graphical menu should appear, where you have to click-select.

Then load the library to use its functions:

```
library(swirl)
```

Finally, install the course (note: do NOT start `swirl()` before this):

```
> install_from_swirl("R Programming")
  |======================================================================| 100%
| Course installed successfully!
```

Then, to start the course:

```
> swirl()

| Welcome to swirl! Please sign in. If you've been here before, use the same
| name as you did then. If you are new, call yourself something unique.

What shall I call you?
```

Tell me if any (and which) of these steps fails.